# Entropy of two interacting spins with strong magnetic field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, approximations

I want to calculate for two interarcting spins and an applied magnetic field the entropy.  The values for the spins are  $s_1= \pm 1$ and $s_2 = \pm 1$ and the Hamiltonian is given by
\begin{align}
H = - \varepsilon s_1 s_2 \, . 
\end{align}
I can use 
 \begin{align}
Z= 2 \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \cosh(2 \beta h)\, . 
\label{eq:Zmg}
\end{align} for the system with applied magnetic field. Now I want to calculate the entropy  for a strong applied field ($\beta h\gg 1$).

**My Idea:**
The free energy is
\begin{align*}
F= -k_\mathrm{B}T \ln (Z) = -k_\mathrm{B}T \ln\left(2 \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon}  \cosh(2\beta h) \right) 
\end{align*}
and the entropy 
\begin{align*}
S&= - \frac{\partial F}{\partial T}  = k_\mathrm{B}\ln\left(2 \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon}  \cosh(2\beta h) \right)  - k_\mathrm{B}T \frac{1}{k_\mathrm{B}T^{2}}\frac{\varepsilon \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \cosh(2 \beta h) + 2 h \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \sinh(2 \beta h) }{\mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \cosh(2 \beta h)} \\
&= k_\mathrm{B}\ln\left(2 \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon}  \cosh(2\beta h) \right)  -\frac{1}{T} \frac{\varepsilon \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \cosh(2 \beta h) + 2 h \mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \sinh(2 \beta h) }{\mathrm{e}^{\beta \varepsilon} \cosh(2 \beta h)} 
\end{align*}
For a strong field the entropy is in my opinion $S=-\infty$, but that doesn't make any sense. Please help me how I get this approximation right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $\beta h \gg 1$, you can simplify
$$
\cosh(2\beta h) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}e^{2\beta h}
$$
and find
$$
Z = e^{\beta(\varepsilon + 2h)} \\
F = -(\varepsilon + 2h) \\
S = 0
$$
Indeed, the result $S = 0$ can be inferred from the fact that a large magnetic field allows only on possible state - the state with both spins parallel to the magnetic field.

Another way to reasoning goes like this: If $h$ is large, we can assume $\varepsilon \ll h$. Thus, we can ignore the interaction term in the Hamiltonian. Then, the magnetic field $h$ appears only in form of the product $\beta h$. Thus, increasing the magnetic field has the same effect as decreasing the temperature. Thus, $h \rightarrow \infty$ is the same as $T \rightarrow 0$. However, we know that the entropy goes to zero if the temperature goes to zero.